# How to send plain text JmsMessage with empty header

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-messaging

I want to send a message to an activeMQ and receive it via MQTT.js in the frontend.

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("topic", "Hello World!");
```

I am getting the message, but with a header, that I can not decode.

```
S�A S�)�x-opt-jms-destQ�x-opt-jms-msg-typeQ Ss�   f    
�/ID:myID@�topic://myTopic@@@@�  j��< St�e Sw�  Hello World!
```

Now I am trying to remove the header from my message.

This thread mentions the targetClient property, but this doesn't seam to work with a topic: [Spring JMS Template - remove RFH Header information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212791/spring-jms-template-remove-rfh-header-information)

I also found the MessageBuilder, where I should be able to set an empty header, but this MessageBuilder doesn't work with the jmsTemplate. jmsTemplate only supports the MessageCreator, which doesn't support an empty header.

How can I send a JMS Message in plain text without any header?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Found a workaround, but i'm open for suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291905/how-to-send-a-jms-message-to-activemq-and-decode-it-in-javascript-with-mqttjs-pr/56428319#56428319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the Queue Broker to work with JMS2 fixed this issue.